# CSS Gradient animation not working

Tags: html, css, gradient

I'm trying to make animated CSS gradient background, I'm generating CSS for gradient on this page: http://www.gradient-animator.com/
Here is the css:

```
body {
background: linear-gradient(270deg, #18f0b8, #18a2f0, #db5640);
background-size: 600% 600%;
-webkit-animation: Gradient 60s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: Gradient 60s ease infinite;
animation: Gradient 60s ease infinite;
@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes Gradient { 
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
}
```

It outputs gradient fine, but it wont animate it. Am I missing something?
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9s9g6ktu/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yup....  You've got to close off your `body` css and have your keyframe animations in their own accord.  Like this http://jsfiddle.net/9s9g6ktu/1/